# In Assembly, Am I missing something with the cmp command?

Tags: assembly

So I place zero both on [ebp-2] and [ebp-4] and i try to convert the separate characters to their real integer values. My problem is when I input '00' , the program does not jump to the label i specified.

```
sub byte[ebp-2],30h   ; convert characters to integer
sub byte[ebp-4],30h
mov al,10       ;multiply by 10 for the tens value
mul byte[ebp-2] 
add ax,[ebp-4] ; add the ones to the computed tens value which is contained in ax
cmp ax,0
je cond_while1
```

At first, i thought ax might not be getting the value but no, ax gets the real value of the integer .I test it by printing the value. Here is how I test it:

```
mov [ebp+4],ax
add byte[ebp+4],30h  ;convert it back to character
mov eax,4  ;print it out
mov ebx,1
lea ecx,[ebp+4]
mov edx,1
int 80h
```

The code above prints 0 when i input 00 and 1 when i input 01 which means there is nothing wrong with me converting the values. Am I missing something with the cmp command? I am still learning assembly so I don't know if i missed a point or something about the cmp command.

Comment: The first thing to learn is how to run an assembly language debugger, and step through the code.  Then you can see where it deviates from what you expect it to do, and that's usually an indication of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
add ax,[ebp-4]
```

you also add in the high byte at [ebp-3]. This is most probably not empty. I even guess it contains an 0xA value (linefeed) ...
A solution might be

```
movzx bx,[ebp-4]
add ax,bx
```